# Queuing images path when there's no internet connection

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, queue, sharedpreferences

I'm havin difficulties of keeping track of my queue.
I'm trying to store image-paths into a queue so i can use the queue to start uploading my images once there's internet (at a later moment). The upload image is an asynctask and in the postExecute i'm trying to send a mail with the uploaded picture attached to it in another asynctask.

This is my UploadImage AsyncTask. I think i'm doing way too difficult and that it can be done much easier than it is right now.

```
private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    /**
     * Private integer which counts how many times we've tried to upload the
     * Image.
     */
    private int _counter = 0;

    private List<String> imageUploadList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context)){
            if(isPhotoTaken()){
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(Step4.this);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.uploadingMessage));
                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.uploadingTitle));
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        init();
        postData();
        return null;
    }
    public void init(){
        _counter = 0;
        _beenHere = true;
        for(String path : imageUploadList){
            Debug.out("Path: "+path);
        }
    }
    public void postData() {
        if (isPhotoTaken()) {
            if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context)){
                if(_beenHere){
                    ImageUploader.uploadFile(getPhotoPath(),
                            "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php", Step4.this);
                } else {
                    for(String path : imageUploadList){
                        Debug.out(path);
                        ImageUploader.uploadFile(path,
                                "http://obo.nl/android-upload-image.php", Step4.this);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (_counter == 0) {
                    _counter++;
                    _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(_context,
                                    getString(R.string.noInternetImageNotUploaded),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    imageUploadList.add(getPhotoPath());
                }
                try {
                    if(_beenHere){
                        _beenHere = false;
                        goToNextIntent();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
                postData();
            }
        }
    }

    private void goToNextIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Step4.this, Step5.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, (Serializable) _user);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, _isRepairable);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE3, _injury);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE4, _category);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE5, _inch);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE6, _size);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(isPhotoTaken()){
            if(dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        mailing(_isRepairable);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(_mail);
    }
}
```

The line:

```
if(AppStatus.haveNetworkConnection(_context))
```

returns a boolean true if the user has a working internet connection. false otherwise.

What I want is to queue all the image paths (and mails sent afterwards) in the desired ArrayList so i can send them all at a later moment when the user has a working internet Connection. Please help me out!

Comment: You want sent email in any case or when all images was downloaded? What you want to do if there is no internet connection? Show any progress bar or something else?

Comment: When there's no internet connection it gives a Toast saying the photo's and mail will be sent later. So the user can go to the next step. But when the whole application is finished, and the user starts the app again to review a 2nd picture, the image list is empty again. So therefore i need a method to save the list somewhere to get a complete list of what needs to be sent

Comment: Ok, in this case you can store failed images in preferences/file and you can create service, that will be work in background and check failed images with some interval. if internet connection available - run new task to download and image send email